# Why does this mesh change shape when rotated?

Tags: mesh, rigging, pose-mode

I've been working on a character model for VRChat! However, I've encountered a problem. When I rotate the eyes, they appear to change in shape:

[image: Rotation of the eye, demonstrating how it "flattens" when rotated.]

Here it is in wireframe mode:

[image: Rotation of the eye in wireframe mode, illustrating the warping effect.]

How do I get these eyes to retain their shape as they rotate?

You can find the .blend file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HMcGs6_Ywr4_27JeV4JhbpiClMgfGr55/view?usp=sharing)!

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed it! All I had to do was set the eye's weights on the head vertex group to zero. I just had to make sure the eyes were parented to the eye bones and nothing else!